# Use a true false statement to control a click function

Tags: jquery, html

I have three separate "#boxes" that .slideToggle independently when a specific .click occurs to each one's "#switch". I'd like to add a "#masterSwitch" that controls all three "#boxes" at the same with a .slideOpen or .slideClose. The trick is getting  all three "#boxes" to all close or open at the same time, regardless of their current state. (one may be open, one may be closed, so .slideToggle won't offer the right solution). So I want to create a true or false statement to tell the "#masterSwitch" what to do. Any suggestions to get this written correctly?

```
// Master Box Control
$('#masterSwitch').click(function(){
    if ($('#box01').is(":visible")) {
        $('#masterSwitch').is(true);
    } else {
        .is(false);
    });

    if ($('#box02').is(":visible")) {
        $('#masterSwitch').is(true);
    } else {
        .is(false);
    });

    if ($('#box03').is(":visible")) {
        $('#masterSwitch').is(true);
    } else {
        .is(false);
    });

    if ($('#masterSwitch').is(true)) {
        $('#box01', '#box02', '#box03').slideOpen(function()
    });

    if ($('#masterSwitch').is(false)) {
        $('#box01', '#box02', '#box03').slideClose(function()
        });
    });

    // Seperate Box Controls
    $('#box01Switch').click(function() {
        $('#box01').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#box02Switch').click(function() {
        $('#box02').slideToggle();
    });

    $('#box03Switch').click(function() {
        $('#box03').slideToggle();
    });
```

Thanks in advance, and please pardon my poor syntax.

Comment: `var closed = false;  $('#masterSwitch').click(function(){  if(closed){$('#box01', ...).slideOpen(); } else{//close}  closed=!closed; });  `

Comment: @TCHdvlp, is that a question or an answer?

Comment: give the same class name to 3 box

Comment: What element type is #masterSwitch? Checkbox? You'll get better replies if you provide the HTML code.

Comment: @trincot More a hint. A boolean variable could be used to flag weather or not we shall open or close `var closed` and of course, switch it each time it is clicked`closed = !=closed`

Comment: @TCHdvlp, that is a lot of code for a hint. Did you read the comment box hint before typing?

Comment: Haven't gotten this to work yet, so I've set it up in a fiddle with revisions. Anyone care to have a look.
[link] https://jsfiddle.net/jamiekayam/xd5p2k66/

Answer (score 0):

Straightforwardly, you can test the instantaneous state of the boxes, then slideUp/slideDown accordingly :

```
$('#masterSwitch').click(function() {
    var $boxes = $('#box01', '#box02', '#box03');
    var isVisible = $boxes.filter(':visible').length > 0; 
    $boxes[isVisible ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']();
});
```

However, one or more of the boxes might be undergoing an animation when the masterSwitch is clicked. If so, the new `slideUp`/`slideDown` commands will be queued so you might choose to `.stop()` before ordering the new animation :

```
$('#masterSwitch').click(function() {
    var $boxes = $('#box01', '#box02', '#box03');
    var isVisible = $boxes.filter(':visible').length > 0; // `true` if one or more of the boxes is visible.
    $boxes.stop()[isVisible ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']();
});
```

Further to that consideration, the boxes might be heading towards being all `hidden` but haven't got there yet, in which case you might expect them all to `.slideDown()`. To ensure masterSwitch's action is correct for the boxes eventual state, you can either ...

... force completion with .stop(true) :

```
$('#masterSwitch').click(function() {
    var $boxes = $('#box01', '#box02', '#box03');
    var isVisible = $boxes.filter(':visible').length > 0; 
    $boxes.stop(true)[isVisible ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']();
});
```

... or await any running animations to complete :

```
$('#masterSwitch').click(function() {
    var $boxes = $('#box01', '#box02', '#box03');
    $boxes.promise().then(function() {
        var isVisible = $boxes.filter(':visible').length > 0; 
        $boxes[isVisible ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']();
    });
});
```

It's hard to predict which of the above will give the best effect. Suggest you try them all out against multiple, rapid clicks of the masterSwitch.